# How to only output a line if a column contains a certain string

Tags: shell, ubuntu

I have 4 columns and the 3rd one contains the letters A-G. I only want to output a line if it the column is non empty or contains an A-G.
This is my code now. Reading in from a compressed file.

```
bzcat $file | cut -d, -f3,4,20,21 |grep -E '[A-G]'|head -100
```

Comment: The 3rd column contains the letters A-G, and you want an output if it contains A-G. That means you want everything?

Comment: You need to make your question clearer, and to provide a sample of a line you accept, and a sample line you reject.

Comment: “Non-empty” would include anything, so why bother checking for A-G?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit confused, but it seems clear that the tool best for the job is going to be `awk`. If I understand what you are looking for, try this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}$3~/[A-G]+/{print}'
```

1. `FS=` defines the field separator, ie. what separates your columns.
2. `$3` is the third field, ie. column.
3. `~/[A-G]+/` tells `awk` to match a regex of only characters A-G..

`awk` is a line-oriented stream editor. It will proceed through your input stream, eg. your `bzcat $file |` and check the third 'field' of each line for the matching regex, and if it matches, will run the command list within the braces, in this case just a simple print statement, which defaults to printing the entire line.

`awk` is a great and very powerful / feature-rich program, and is worthwhile to learn at least its basics. Check out its `man` page for more.